# Unable to find the google-lifesciences argument on snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have been working through the snakemake executor's script and I am getting this error:

```
snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments: --google-lifesciences --google-lifesciences-region
```

code:

```
snakemake --google-lifesciences --default-remote-prefix disha_lodha/data  --use-conda --google-lifesciences-region us-west1.
```

Can someone suggest how to resolve this issue?.

Comment: What is your snakemake version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your Snakemake to at least 5.18, which is when [support for Google Life Sciences API](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/releases/tag/v5.18.0) was officially added.